# How to interpret CPU load average?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, cpu-load

When I use command `mpstat`, I see an `idle` value, for example 25%. It means 75% of CPU power is used.

If there are 4 cores on CPU, then does `25% idle` mean that 3 cores are fully used and 1 core is not used at all?

What command shall I use to see the total CPU usage of all cores?

Comment: That's not the load average btw. There is a distinction between CPU utilization and the load average. A CPU can only be utilized up to 100%, the load average describes somewhat of a queue of tasks that wait for the CPU. Thus, the queue can grow longer than 100% (which would be full utilization).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see the stats for all individual cores, use `mpstat -P ALL`:

[image]

Without `-P ALL`, you'll get the average of all cores. Displayed in the shown output in the `all` line.

Answer (score 2):

25% idle on a four core machine means that the average core was 25% idle. That could mean that three cores were used all the time and one was idle. It could also mean that all four cores were active 75% of the time. It can mean anything in-between.

> What command shall I use to see the total CPU usage of all cores?

It's just math. If you have 4 cores and they were 25% idle, the total CPU usage of all cores is

  **4**
  * (1 -
  **25**
  /100)

or 3.0 -- the equivalent of three cores at 100% usage.

If you want to see individual cores, the easiest way is to run `top` and then hit the `1` key to show all cores. You can then use `H` to show threads and `f j <enter>` to show which core each thread last ran on (the `P` column).